# Replicating results using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, replication

I am trying to replicate results of my experiments using Tensorflow and Keras (with TF backend). When I use TF, I set random seeds for numpy and tensorflow graphs first right at the top of the script. I am not using any dropout layers or other methods that could introduce randomness (that I can think of).

When running such models, regardless of it's network size, always yields same results.

TF Experiment 1:

('Epoch ', 99, ' completed out of ', 100, ' loss: ', 289.8982433080673, 'accuracy: ', 0.6875)

TF Experiment 2:

('Epoch ', 99, ' completed out of ', 100, ' loss: ', 289.8982433080673, 'accuracy: ', 0.6875)

When I tried to replicate these results using Keras with same configurations, I failed. On top of that, each separate run yields different performance.

My TF code, which can replicate results, looks like this: 
Snippet Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhpvH5DuVu8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=46

```py
from numpy.random import seed                                                                                                                           
seed(1)                                                                                                                                                 
from tensorflow import set_random_seed                                                                                                                  
set_random_seed(2)                                                                                                                                      

## import system modules                                                                                                                                
#
import os                                                                                                                                               
import sys                                                                                                                                              

## import ML modules                                                                                                                                    
#
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                                                 
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                      
from keras.utils import to_categorical                                                                                                                  
from sklearn import preprocessing                                                                                                                       

logs_path = '../logs/'                                                                                                                                                                                                    

## Default constants                                                                                                                                    
#
NO_OF_CLASSES = 2                                                                                                                                       
BATCH_SIZE = 32                                                                                                                                         
FEAT_DIM = 26                                                                                                                                           
N_nodes_hl1 = 300                                                                                                                                       
N_nodes_hl2 = 30                                                                                                                                        
N_nodes_hl3 = 30                                                                                                                                        

## define the network architecture                                                                                                                      
#                                                                                                                                                       
## This model is a simple multilayer perceptron network with 3 hidden layers.                                                                           
## Input to the layer has the dimensions equal to feature dimensions.                                                                                   
## We create a complete graph in this method with input placeholder as an input argument and                                                            
## output placeholder as an returning argument                                                                                                          
#
def neural_network_model(data):                                                                                                                         

    ## defining dictionaries specifying the specification of each layer.                                                                                
    #
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FEAT_DIM, N_nodes_hl1]), name='w1'),\                                                    
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl1]), name='b1')}                                                                

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl1, N_nodes_hl2]), name='w2'), \                                                
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl2]), name='b2')}                                                                

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl2, N_nodes_hl3]), name='w3'),\                                                 
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl3]), name='b3')}                                                                

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_nodes_hl3, NO_OF_CLASSES]), name='w4'), \                                                
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([NO_OF_CLASSES]), name='b4')}                                                              

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])                                                                   
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)                                                                                 

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])                                                                     
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)                                                                                

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])                                                                     
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)                                                                                  

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'], name="last_layer")                                                  

    ## return the final layer's output gracefully                                                                                                       
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    return output    

## end of method                                                                                                                                        
#                                                                                                                                                       

## This method trains a neural network along with collecting statistics related to                                                                      
## the graphs.                                                                                                                                          
#
def train_neural_network(xtrain, ytrain, odir):                                                                                                         

    learning_rate = 0.0008                                                                                                                              
    epoch_iter = 100                                                                                                                                    

    ## input/ output  placeholders where data would be plugged in...                                                                                    
    #
    x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, FEAT_DIM], name="input")                                                                                         
    y_ = tf.placeholder('float', name="output")                                                                                                         

    ## define the network                                                                                                                               
    #
    logits = neural_network_model(x)                                                                                                                    
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="op_to_restore") ## softmax normalizes the output results

    loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = y_) )                                                      

    ## Major OP for the training procedure. The "train" op defined here tries to minimize loss                                                          
    #
    with tf.name_scope('ADAM'):                                                                                                                         
        # Gradient Descent                                                                                                                              
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)                                                                                               
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss)                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):                                                                                                                     
        ## Accuracy calculation by comparing the predicted and detected labels                                                                          
        #
        acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))                                                                                          
        acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))                                                                                                  

    ## summary and display variables                                                                                                                    
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    loss_sum = tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)                                                                                                          
    acc_sum = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", acc)                                                                                                        

   ## Merge all summaries into a single variable. This summaries will be displayed using Tensorboard                                                   
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_sum, acc_sum])                                                                                

    ## create a session for the graph (graph initialization)                                                                                            
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                          

        ## initialize all the variables. Note that before this point, all the variables were empty buckets !!                                           
        #
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())                                                                                                     

        ## initialize the summary writer (For tensorboard)                                                                                              
        #
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())                                                                 

        ## iterate over epochs (complete forward-backward for the entire training set)                                                                  
        #                                                                                                                                               
        for epoch in range(epoch_iter):                                                                                                                 

            ## initialize some variables to keep track of progress during training                                                                      
            #                                                                                                                                           
            epoch_loss = 0                                                                                                                              
            epoch_accuracy = 0                                                                                                                          

            ## minibatch training. Splitting input data in to smaller chunks is better                                                                  
            #                                                                                                                                           
            for i in range( int(len(xtrain)/ BATCH_SIZE) ):                                                                                             
                epoch_x = xtrain[ i * BATCH_SIZE : i * BATCH_SIZE + BATCH_SIZE]                                                                         
                epoch_y = ytrain[ i * BATCH_SIZE : i * BATCH_SIZE + BATCH_SIZE]                                                                         

                ## run the session and collect the intermediate stats. Feed dict kwarg takes in input/output placeholdar names as                       
                ## a key and features/labels as values                                                                                                  
                #                                                                                                                                       
                _, ac, ls, summary = sess.run([train, acc, loss, merged_summary_op], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y_: epoch_y})                             

                ## write the the summary in logs to visualize it later                                                                                     
                #                                                                                                                                       
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch * int(len(xtrain)/BATCH_SIZE)+i)                                                              

                ## update stats                                                                                                                         
                #                                                                                                                                       
                epoch_loss += ls                                                                                                                        
                epoch_accuracy += ac                                                                                                                    

            print ("Epoch ", epoch, " completed out of ", epoch_iter, " loss: ", epoch_loss, "accuracy: ", ac)                                          
        ## saver module to save tf graph variables.. etc....
```

My Keras script to replicate results looks as follows:

```py
from numpy.random import seed                                                                                                                           
seed(1)                                                                                                                                                 
from tensorflow import set_random_seed                                                                                                                  
set_random_seed(2)                                                                                                                                      


## import system modules                                                                                                                                
#                                                                                                                                                       
import os                                                                                                                                               
import sys                                                                                                                                              

## import ML and datatype modules                                                                                                                       
#                                                                                                                                                       
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import keras                                                                                                                                            
from keras.models import Sequential                                                                                                                     
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout                                                                                                                 
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint                                                                                                             
from keras.optimizers import SGD                                                                                                                        
from keras.utils import to_categorical                                                                                                                  
from sklearn import preprocessing                                                                                                                       

## Default constants                                                                                                                                    
#                                                                                                                                                       
NO_OF_CLASSES = 2                                                                                                                                       
BATCH_SIZE = 32                                                                                                                                         
FEAT_DIM = 26                                                                                                                                           
N_nodes_hl1 = 300                                                                                                                                       
N_nodes_hl2 = 30                                                                                                                                        
N_nodes_hl3 = 30                                                                                                                                        


## This method defines the NN architecture as well as performs training and saves the model info                                                        
#                                                                                                                                                       
def train_neural_network(xtrain, ytrain, odir):                                                                                                         
    learning_rate = 0.009                                                                                                                               

    ## Define the network (MLP)                                                                                                                         
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    model = Sequential()                                                                                                                                
    model.add(Dense(N_nodes_hl1, input_dim=FEAT_DIM, activation="relu"))                                                                                
    model.add(Dense(N_nodes_hl2, activation="relu"))                                                                                                    
    model.add(Dense(N_nodes_hl3, activation="relu"))                                                                                                    
    model.add(Dense(NO_OF_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))                                                                                               

    ## optimizer                                                                                                                                        
    #                                                                                                                                                   
    sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate)                                                                                                                         
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])                                                                 
    print model.summary()                                                                                                                               
    ## train the model                                                                                                                                  
    model.fit(x=xtrain, y=ytrain, epochs=100)
```

Keras experiment1:
loss: 0.5964 - acc: 0.6725

Keras experiment2:
loss: 0.5974 - acc: 0.6712

The only difference between two scripts is the optimizer. I don't think that would introduce any randomness during training. Also, I believe that NN architecture should yield same results with the precision upto float64 on CPUs (and float32 on GPUs due to hardware capabilities).

What am I missing in my Keras script? Also, correct me if my understanding is wrong somewhere in this query.

Along with that, additional references (other than the following) on how to replicate NN results would be highly appreciated.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/

[How to get stable results with TensorFlow, setting random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed)

[Getting reproducible results using tensorflow-gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865665/getting-reproducible-results-using-tensorflow-gpu)